# Using the for attribute in JSX - linter unknown property "for"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a label with an input. I want to make the whole label area clickable to trigger the input (a checkbox). So I have used the `for` attribute as I believe this is exactly what it is intended for:

```
<label for={id}>
    <input
        name="checkbox"
        type="radio"
        data-id={id}
    />
</label>
```

Functionally this *works* but the linter does not like it:

> error  Unknown property 'for' found, use 'htmlFor' instead  react/no-unknown-property

`htmlFor` does not appear to have the same functionality as the `for` attribute.

How can I change my code to make it work whilst retaining the functionality of `for` - I'd rather avoid writing a custom function that selects the correlating checkbox when you click on the label when that functionality already exists with `for`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special you need to do.Try This,

```
    <input
        name="checkbox"
        type="radio"
        data-id={id}
    />
<label htmlFor={id}></label>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the functionality of `for` doesn't work

Comment: htmlFor or for just refer to target, nothing else.

Comment: I meant that the use of `for` (to make the label be able to action the input) did nothing. However, it appears I had a false positive and in the code above it shouldn't have worked, because there was no `id` on the input. I had thought it was using `data-id` - weirdly it still worked when using `for`

Comment: I am not hetting what you saying. htmlFor and For wprk same way. If anything not working for you, it is noy bcoz of htmlFor

Answer (score 0):

### **Just replace `for` with `htmlFor`.**

---

As in React `class` becomes `className`, `for` becomes `htmlFor`.

If you do `document.getElementById` you will have to access `for` property as `label.htmlFor`, as under the hood JavaScript uses `htmlFor`.

You can read about it here : [prop_label_htmlfor](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_label_htmlfor.asp), [React htmlfor](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor)

Eslint suggestion for reference :

[image: htmlFor]